# pdfBox - contentStream.concatenate2CTM full documentation parameters

Tags: java, pdfbox

jsf 2.1 /
pdfbox

Im tring to generate landscape pdfbox pdf and draw some strings to its contents but I didnt find any full specification about concatenate2CTM method.

Does anyone have some full information about the concatenate 2CTM parameters

I have only this ***but does not help me*** because I dont know what value I must enter.

what means a...f operator ???

[image]

Comment: Have you read Chapter 4 "Graphics" of the latest version of Adobe's "PDF Reference"? The "full information" you ask for is in described in the reference (4.2 "Coordinate systems"); it assumes a basic understanding of the underlying math.

Comment: thanks so much @Jongware. Ive downloaded pdf reference and got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directly adds a **cm** operation to the content stream in question. Thus, you find those values `a..f` specified in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> *a b c d e f* **cm** Modify the current transformation matrix (CTM) by concatenating the specified matrix (see 8.3.2, "Coordinate Spaces"). Although the operands specify a matrix, they shall be written as six separate numbers, not as an array.
>
> *(Table 57)*

In section 8.3.3 *Common Transformations* you'll find some basic transformations: translations, scalings, rotation, and skews. You'll want to use a rotation and probably also a translation.

Section 8.3.4 *Transformation Matrices* then discusses the mathematics of transformation matrices. Especially it shows that `a..f` actually denote the transformation described by the matrix

```
┌ a b 0 ┐
│ c d 0 │
└ e f 1 ┘
```

operating on the plane of vectors `[ x y 1 ]` by right-multiplication.

Comment: can you tell what is this `cm`? what is `cm operator`?

Comment: The specification of the **cm** operation is quoted from the PDF specification in my answer. Which detail do you not understand? Regardless, though, you should read the PDF specification (linked in my answer).