# Understanding TextPosition getTextMatrix() method in pdfBox 2.0.3

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to discover the character positioning inside the pdf pages. I have implemented a class `TextPosition` which extends `PDFTextStripper`, and I have used `setSortByPosition(true)` to arrange the `charactersByArticle` according to page structure. I have a pdf (here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9q9YK3qNDvxYWpfQUFSMk1DZHc/view?usp=sharing), refer to page 10) in which I have both landscape and potrait characters. My `TextPosition` class has all the sorted characters at every page. Now when I see page 10, The landscape characters come after the potrait characters order. Here is the code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        TextExtractor textExtractor = new TextExtractor("C:\\Users\\prabhjot.rai\\Desktop\\Demo\\sbet201601.pdf");
        PDFPage page = textExtractor.getPages().get(10);
        for (List<TextPosition> article: page.getCharactersByArticle()) {
            for (TextPosition text: article) {
                System.out.print(text.getUnicode() + " ");
                System.out.print(text.getX() + " ");
                System.out.print(text.getTextMatrix() + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the last lines of page 10 output:

```
1 406.46 [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,406.46,64.9355] 
4 410.64938 [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,410.64938,64.9355] 
Y 250.9882 [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,250.9882,46.5761] 
E 256.3768 [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,256.3768,46.5761] 
A 261.7654 [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,261.7654,46.5761] 
R 267.15402 [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,267.15402,46.5761] 
P 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,118.1203] 
e 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,123.499886] 
r 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,127.680466] 
c 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,130.07147] 
e 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,134.25516] 
n 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,138.43575] 
t 94.1495 [0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,142.61633] 
9 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,37.2] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,41.220325] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,43.199364] 
| 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,45.178402] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,46.678642] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,48.838825] 
N 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,50.817863] 
F 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,56.579422] 
I 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,61.016304] 
B 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,63.65609] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,68.99631] 
S 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,71.09585] 
m 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,75.53273] 
a 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,81.59274] 
l 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,85.135864] 
l 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,87.3543] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,89.57274] 
B 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,91.79278] 
u 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,97.132996] 
s 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,101.15252] 
i 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,104.2727] 
n 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,106.491135] 
e 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,110.51146] 
s 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,114.05458] 
s 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,117.17476] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,120.294136] 
E 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,122.334625] 
c 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,127.19444] 
o 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,130.73756] 
n 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,134.75789] 
o 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,138.77742] 
m 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,142.79774] 
i 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,148.85776] 
c 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,151.0762] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,154.61932] 
T 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,156.71886] 
r 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,161.57947] 
e 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,164.21924] 
n 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,167.76236] 
d 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,171.78268] 
s 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,175.80222] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,178.9224] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,180.84238] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,182.82141] 
M 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,184.8] 
o 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,191.46011] 
n 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,195.48204] 
t 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,199.50397] 
h 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,201.72401] 
l 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,205.74594] 
y 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,207.96599] 
  486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,211.50592] 
R 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,213.48495] 
e 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,218.34477] 
p 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,221.8847] 
o 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,225.90663] 
r 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,229.92856] 
t 486.465 [0.0,7.98,-7.98,0.0,486.465,233.04794]
```

I can definitely see that the `getTextMatrix()` yields different matrix for both landscape and potrait characters. (Potrait: `[7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,406.46,64.9355]`, Landscape: `[0.0,7.7706,-7.787,0.0,94.1495,118.1203]`, landscape starts with zero at first place in matrix). I want to understand the matrix more so that I can make a clear distinction between two types. I referred the [documentation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/text/TextPosition.html#getTextMatrix()) but couldn't comprehend much. Can anyone share some article or thoughts on this?

Comment: This is the moment that you realize that school math is also used in the real world. Anyway, google "affine transform matrix", and especially the part about rotation. That is where the "-" is for. Re [7.787,0.0,0.0,7.7706,406.46,64.9355], the two 7.* are the x and y scales, the last two numbers are the x and y translation (= move). In the rotated matrix it is more tricky. See also the DrawPrintTextLocations example for how to use these values.

Comment: Prabhjot Rai: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21335785/1729265) contains pointers where to look for the specification of the syntactic details. The rest is trivial linear algebra.